# Debugging addition statement inside if statement

Tags: python

I'm making a python program to ask users whether they want to add or remove items from a list, and then printing the length of the list when the user quits the program. Right now I'm building the function to handle user inputs and the `length` variable isn't incrementing by 1 each time the user presses 'A'. Can anyone take a look and see why this is the case?

Edit: I'm not allowed to use the `len()` function, otherwise I wouldn't bother with the length counter

```
actions = ['A', 'Q', 'R']

def inputLogic(user_input):
    length = 0
    if user_input == actions[0]:
        length += 1
        user_add_input = int(input('What number would you like to add to the list? '))
        list.append(user_add_input)
        print(list)
        print(length)
    
def main():
    user_input_choice = input("Type 'A' if you want to add a value to the list, 'R' if you want to remove a value, or 'Q' if you want to quit ").upper()
    while user_input_choice in actions:
        inputLogic(user_input_choice)
        user_input_choice = input("Type 'A' if you want to add a value to the list, 'R' if you want to remove a value, or 'Q' if you want to quit ").upper()
main()
```

Update: I realize why this is now - I was defining `length` within the scope of the function instead of outside, so it always reset to 0 and got 1 added to it.

Comment: Do you still have a question, or can this be deleted?

Comment: It can definitely be deleted - I was just editing my questions to try and get rid of my question ban @chepner